# Establish the rule of three

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-verification

Suppose $a,b,c,d \in \Bbb N$
If $a+b=c$ and $d$ divides any two of the aforementioned variables then $d$ divides the third.

What I have so far:
Let $$ {m},{n}\in \Bbb N$$
Let $$ m= \frac{a}{d}$$ 
Let $$ n= \frac{b}{d}$$
Let $$ m+n = q \in \Bbb N $$
Then $$ c= m*d+n*d$$
$$ c= d*q$$
$$\frac{c}{d} = q $$
And since $q\in \Bbb N$ so is $\frac{c}{d}$ and thus c|d.

Is my proof sound?

Answer (score 1):

I do have a number of criticisms/comments.

1. The core idea is right. You seem to know how to use divisibility of $a$ and $b$ by $d$ to obtain the divisibility of $c$ by $d$.
2. You haven't completed the proof. The question asks you to prove that if **any two** of $a, b, c$ are divisible by $d$, then so is the third. What if $a$ and $c$ are divisible by $d$? Or if $b$ and $c$ are divisible by $d$? The proofs are similar, but should not be omitted.
3. The first three steps could be worded better. In particular, I don't like saying "Let $m, n \in \Bbb{N}$" first, as it is an invitation for the reader to replace $m$ and $n$ with any natural number they like. In answer to the first statement, they might think "Cool, I'll try $n = 5$ and $m = 17$". But, this may not match the values of $a$, $b$ or $d$, so the next two "let" statements essentially ask the reader to redefine $m$ and $n$ to something more appropriate.
   What you're really doing is using the definition of divisibility to assert the existence of natural numbers $m$ and $n$, and these numbers will depend on $a, b, d$. I would say instead,

> Suppose $d \mid a$ and $d \mid b$. Then, there exist $m$ and $n$ such that $a = md$ and $b = nd$.

On a vaguely similar note, I would prefer "Let $q = m + n \in \Bbb{N}$", rather than  "Let $m + n = q \in \Bbb{N}$", since it reads like you're defining the value of the sum of $m$ and $n$, rather than the value of $q$. Or you can simply note

> $$c = md + nd = (m + n)d \text{ and } m + n \in \Bbb{N}.$$

Comment: Alr thank you so much, this is exactly the input I was looking for. I’m learning a lot about proof writing but I still clearly have a ways to go.

Comment: @Christheyankee This is exactly how you learn. :-)